# lsqcurvefit fails depending on platform

Tags: matlab

I am trying to process an extremely large dataset which requires that I do several million non-linear curve fits. I have acquired a dedicated piece of code that is designed to be used for the data I have collected, which at its heart uses the MATLAB function `lsqcurvefit`. All works well when I run it on my laptop, except that the fitting is too slow to be useful to me right now, which is not too surprising considering that the model function is quite complicated. To put this in perspective, my laptop can only process about 8000 fits per hour, and I have on the order of tens of millions of fits to do.

Fortunately I have access to a computing cluster at my institution, which should enable me to process this data in a more reasonable time frame. The issue that has arisen is that - despite being cross-platform - there seems to be some significant difference between what the MATLAB code is doing on my Windows laptop and the cluster. Despite running the exact same code, on exactly the same data, with the same version of MATLAB, the code running on the Unix cluster fails with the following error message:

```
Error using eig
Input to EIG must not contain NaN or Inf.

Error in trust (line 29)
    [V,D] = eig(H);

Error in trdog (line 109)
    [st,qpval,po,fcnt,lambda] = trust(rhs,MM,delta);

Error in snls (line 311)
    [sx,snod,qp,posdef,pcgit,Z] = trdog(x,g,A,D,delta,dv,...

Error in lsqncommon (line 156)
                snls(funfcn,xC,lb,ub,flags.verbosity,options,defaultopt,initVals.F,initVals.J,caller,
             ...

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 254)
    lsqncommon(funfcn,xCurrent,lb,ub,options,defaultopt,caller,...
```

I can confirm that there are no infinities or NaNs in my data, which this error message might initially seem to suggest. I can only conclude that using a different platform leads to some differing accuracy in execution, which probably leads to a divide by zero error somewhere along the way. My question is - how can I make this code run on the cluster?

For reference, my laptop is running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, with an Intel i5 5200U 2.20GHz x4, and the cluster runs Scientific Linux 6.7 x86_64, with various Intel Xeon proccessors, with both running MATLAB R2015b.

Comment: Matlab error messages are usually pretty accurate.  If you can run Matlab interactively on the cluster, then setting the breakpoints to stop on an error (either using the menu, or issue the command `dbstop if error`), and examining the variables in the calling function stack would be a good place to start.  If you can't do this, then insert debugging code for tests such as: `if any(isnan(H)), disp('H has at least one NaN'); elseif any(isinf(H)), disp('H has at least one Inf'); end`, into trust.m just before the call to eig would be very useful

Comment: I should have said, rather than using `dbstop if error`, you could also use `dbstop if naninf` which breaks execution at any line that returns a NaN or an Inf value.  Of course, that only works if you can run interactively on the cluster!